are printf and scanf used safely here in this code?
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[12];

    int b = scanf("%11s", a);

    if (b != 1) { return 1; };

    if (printf("%s", a) > 11) {
       
        return 1;
    };

    return 0;
}

1 - are scanf and printf here used safely ?
2 - am i missing some checks ? i wanna make 100% bug free code in c
3 - is the only issue in scanf buffer overflow ? is it fixed in the above code ?
the purpose of all this is to make a c 100% safe code

While you should always check what scanf returns, you seldom, if ever, need to check the result of printf. With that said, your code, as currently shown, is fine.

That really depends on what you mean by safety... You certainly won't have security issues here

to add extra security and also to prevent ub

Actually, you do have one problem: What happens if the user inputs a string into a that is shorter than 11 characters? Then printf will return a value shorter than 11. Is that considered a problem, or not? It's not clear from the code.

The only reason to check the return value of printf is to verify that the underlying write worked, but it's not likely to fail until the fsync or the fclose.  In this case, if the write fails, it won't go detected until program termination when fclose is implicitly called.  Since you're not emitting an error message anyway, there's no point checking the return value.


= means should not be more than 11


Also note that the C standard values from the main function is either EXIT_SUCCESS (usually 0) or EXIT_FAILURE (usually 1). As you only return 0 there's no way to check if the program have failed or not.

but i should not return 0 from main

it has to be returned from the if statement i know i will have to add a descriptive message since this is for debbuging purposes i did not add the msg

aah ok ok i get ur point i have to return 1 not 0

Rule of thumb: If there's an error return EXIT_FAILURE;. Otherwise return EXIT_SUCCESS;.

The printf check can never fail. The scanf format guarantees that a will be no longer than 11, so it can't print more than that.

BTW, it's generally a good idea to print a newline before exiting. Otherwise the command prompt will be on the same line as the output, which can be confusing.

You don't need the null statements after the close brace of the if statements.  Remove those semicolons.

i wanna make 100% bug free code in c  One thing that can really help with that is using a consistent style for your code.  As currently posted, your code uses different indentation styles for your if statements, for example.  That makes your code harder to read and therefore more likely to contain bugs.
